# Get page id or status by private pages?

Tags: functions, pages

How can I get post id or status by private pages if user is not logged in?

This don't works:

```
get_the_ID()
get_post_status ( $ID )
```

I found some usefull informatins [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_status) but is not enough to detect how can I get this data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check you're using these functions correctly. Try collecting the results and output them in order to see what you're working with.

[`get_the_ID()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_ID/) and [`get_queried_object_id()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object_id/) are two good ways to get the current ID, so pass them to [`get_post_status()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_status).

```
$debug = array (
    'get_the_ID'                   => get_the_ID(),
    'get_the_ID_status'            => get_post_status( get_the_ID() ),
    'get_queried_object_id'        => get_queried_object_id(),
    'get_queried_object_id_status' => get_post_status( get_queried_object_id() ),
);

// print the results to the screen
echo '<pre>';
var_dump( $debug );
echo '</pre>';
```

ID of the current item in the WordPress Loop.

```
if ( get_post_status( get_the_ID() ) == 'private' ) {
    echo ' get_the_ID = private ';
} else {
    echo ' get_the_ID = public ';
}
```

ID of the current queried object

```
if ( get_post_status( get_queried_object_id() ) == 'private' ) {
    echo ' get_queried_object_id = private ';
} else {
    echo ' get_queried_object_id = public ';
}
```